# Mead is taking up space in my carboys. When can I bottle it?

Tags: mead

So the mead I made six weeks ago did not taste great when I moved it into secondary. Plenty of solvent notes.  I have big plans for lager season and want that secondary back. I'm planning on force carbonating for a sparkling mead. Can I do so, then put it in bottles for the rest of its conditioning?

Comment: is this a straight mead, or a fruit or herb?

Comment: Straight dry mead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can transfer the mead from secondary into a keg for extended conditioning.  In my experience it is better to bulk condition, then any adjustment that may need to be made can be done before bottling.  These things would include stabilizing, back sweetening, adding acid, etc.  If you bottle and later realize that you should have added some sweetness you will have to open every bottle to achieve this.
This is something I learned from talking with Ken Schramm.

Comment: I agree with Chris.  My strawberry mead (melomel really) took nearly a year to be ready to bottle and another year before becoming drinkable.

Answer (score 0):

The mead will probably take on the order of a year to be ready.   If you're strapped for aging space, you can probably dose it with campden to kill off any remaining yeast, and then force carbonate and finish the rest of the aging in bottles.   As stated above, bulk aging is better if you're expecting to need to make any flavor adjustments to it, though.