# Where to age mead, bottle or secondary fermenter?

Tags: mead, aging

What method is best to age honey wine?

There is a similar  [question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12348/is-it-better-to-age-a-wine-in-bottles-rather-than-bulk-aging) where someone suggests that bulk aging is faster. Has anyone experienced this?

Edit: I found another similar [question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/mead-is-taking-up-space-in-my-carboys-when-can-i-bottle-it?rq=1), one answer indicates that bulk conditioning is more convenient since it offers more control over the bottled product, but does not mention anything about which method offers a faster rate of aging.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the aging process isn't dependent on the volume.

**Couple differences**
To age out fusels there are split opinions on what works better. Bulk / Bottle.

Larger volume will give a more consistent product In the batch. Especially if utilising post fermentation additions. Wood, herbs, organisms etc.

Sometimes a little oxidation aids the flavor which aging with corks allows.

Bottling gives more insurance as a whole against failures. But, has more individual exposures to bacterial contamination from bottling.

Bulk aging puts all your eggs in one basket. If the vessel fails or it gets contaminated its all gone.

Comment: Yep, that sums it up pretty well. Bulk aging technically provides a more consistent batch, but in all honesty, it'd probably be hard to taste the difference between bottles unless they were stored drastically differently. I generally bulk age when possible (or when lazy), unless I need a carboy for something or need to save some space. At the end of the day, though, it doesn't matter all that much.

Comment: Also, I disagree with this statement: "But, [bottling] has more individual exposures to bacterial contamination from bottling." This shouldn't be an issue if you sanitize properly.